# PHP SQLITE3 randomly not inserting data into database

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I'm parsing a json file to add data to a sqlite database. It works fine apart from the fact that some entries I retrieve from the json file are just not added completely. As an example see this array I got from the json file:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 4215717
            [Guid] => a2fd45b0-c602-4c82-bb30-19aba8bfacdf
            [IsRawData] => 
            [Name] => test 1
            [State] => Released
            [Created] => 2015-10-25T10:21:13Z
            [CreatorId] => 65edfb59-8087-4f20-81d8-1dc7b94c5624
            [Modified] => 2020-02-19T13:08:07Z
            [ModifierId] => 65edfb59-8087-4f20-81d8-1dc7b94c5624
            [EntryId] => 377794
            [LanguageId] => Array
                (
                    [PrimaryLangId] => 7
                    [SubLangId] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 4215718
            [Guid] => 4609ace8-8e6f-457d-a0ae-faa29950cdcb
            [IsRawData] => 
            [Name] => test 2
            [State] => Released
            [Created] => 2015-10-25T10:21:41Z
            [CreatorId] => 65edfb59-8087-4f20-81d8-1dc7b94c5624
            [Modified] => 2017-01-18T13:30:05Z
            [ModifierId] => 65edfb59-8087-4f20-81d8-1dc7b94c5624
            [EntryId] => 377794
            [LanguageId] => Array
                (
                    [PrimaryLangId] => 9
                    [SubLangId] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

For some entries I add to the db using the code below, I randomly only have the first entry from the array written to the db and I can't figure out a pattern for which entries it worked and for which ones it didn't.

Is there something wrong with my code? Or do you see any issues that could cause this behaviour?

```
// Prepare statement to propagate terms table
$termStmt = $o_db->prepare("INSERT INTO terms
                    (entryID, termID, term, status, wordclass, usage, type,
                    primaryLangID, secondaryLangID ) 
            VALUES (:entryID, :termID, :term, :status, :wordclass, :usages, :types, 
                    :primaryLangID, :secondaryLangID)");

// Bind term parameters
$termStmt->bindParam(':entryID', $i_entryID);
$termStmt->bindParam(':termID', $i_termID);
$termStmt->bindParam(':term', $s_term);
$termStmt->bindParam(':status', $s_status);
$termStmt->bindParam(':wordclass', $s_wordclass);
$termStmt->bindParam(':usages', $s_usage);
$termStmt->bindParam(':types', $s_type);
$termStmt->bindParam(':project', $s_project);
$termStmt->bindParam(':primaryLangID', $i_primaryLangID);
$termStmt->bindParam(':secondaryLangID', $i_secondaryLangID);

foreach ($a_entryData as $entry){
    $entryID = $entry['entryID']; // entryID comes from another table in the db to get the full entry
    $fullEntry = getEntry($entryID); //get entry from json

    foreach ($fullEntry as $term){
        
        foreach($term as $termEntry) {

            $i_entryID = $termEntry['EntryId'];
            $i_termID = $termEntry['Id'];
            $s_term =$termEntry['Name'];
            $s_status =$termEntry['State'];
            $i_primaryLangID = $termEntry['LanguageId']['PrimaryLangId'];
            $i_secondaryLangID = $termEntry['LanguageId']['SubLangId'];

            // Now get the term properties and the corresponding values
            $a_properties = getTermProperties($i_termID);
            $a_propertyValues = propertyValues($a_properties);

            $a_properties = getTermProperties($i_termID);
            $a_values = propertyValues($a_properties);

            if (isset($a_values['Wortklasse'])){
                $s_wordclass = $a_values['Wortklasse'];
            }else{
                $s_wordclass = "N\A";
            }
            if (isset($a_values['Verwendung'])){
                $s_usage = $a_values['Verwendung'];
            }else{
                $s_usage = "N\A";
            }
            if (isset($a_values['Benennungstyp'])){
                $s_type = $a_values['Benennungstyp'];
            }else{
                $s_type = "N\A";
            }

            // Execute term statement and add data to the table
            $termStmt->execute();

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hi, I would start by echo'ing the values your are binding now, and skip the actual SQLite3 inserts. If you randomly miss entries, it sounds to me something else goes wrong. Also: Did you check the errorlog of PHP? Maybe you'll find a clue there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it with smaller chunks of the json file. Everything worked out fine. But I can't do it for 10000+ entries.

Comment: Check PHP's error log. I think you'll see there what goes wrong (possibly "out of memory"  or something like that)